# mysqli prepared statement get result error

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php
    require 'conn.php';

    $name="gurpreet";
    $roll="16EAYCS032";
    $stream="computer_science";

    $sql="insert into prepare values(?,?,?);";

    $stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sss",$name,$roll,$stream);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result=mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    echo "RESULT <br>";
    if($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<br>Found";
        echo $row['name'];
    }
?>
```

I am getting the output as

> RESULT Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_result,         boolean given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php\php\insert_using_prepare.php on line 23

Comment: You are INSERTing data and then trying to read the result, what are you trying to achieve with this?  Can I also recommend that with your INSERT, that you always list the column names your inserting into, it makes it clear which piece of data is going into which column.

Comment: if we use "select * from prepare";
will it work

Comment: If you are using "select" please update your question accordingly

Comment: Try is with SELECT and see what happens.

Comment: ok , let me try and will post accordingly...Thanks for your response

Comment: <?php

require 'conn.php';

$name="gurpreet";

$sql= "select * from prepare where name=?;";

$stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql);

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$name);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);


$result=mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

echo "RESULT <br>";

if($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

echo "<br>Found<br>";

echo $row['roll'];

}

?>

Comment: worked..Thanks/

Comment: can you please enlighten me more on this topic that is it important to use stmt in functions that can we use only   mysqli_execute($stmt); istead of   mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
i am new to all this

Comment: @NigelRen if you want to help ..please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Nigel comment, when doing `INSERT` statement, the `mysqli_stmt_get_result` return boolean - that why `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` fails.

Getting result from `mysqli_stmt_get_result` should be done with `SELECT`.

Regarding your comment: there is no differece between `mysqli_execute` and `mysqli_stmt_execute` - as you can see in the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-execute.php) - `mysqli_execute` is an alias for  `mysqli_stmt_execute`.